# ¿Como mostrar todo el contenido de una base de datos en HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Buenas necesito saber como hago que la url alojada en mi Base de datos las pueda extraer con php y colocarlas en el "src" de las imágenes para que carguen siempre.
Verán tengo el siguiente problema, estóy haciendo una red social como proyecto de grado, obvio no completa, pero si algo de funciones, me queda una semana, y necesito crear una galería con PHP mysqli AJAX, y ya puedo alojar las url de las fotos en la base de datos, pero no puedo hacer la obtención de esas url por una consulta "fetch_assoc" y me imprima una etiqueta "" por cada url que tenga la base de datos, enrealidad eso es lo que quiero.

Les dejo los codigos para que me ayuden mejor.

PD : **Soy novato en PHP.**

```html
<?php 
    session_start();
    $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];

    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
     $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","imagen"); 
     if (!$conexion) { 
   die("Fallo la conexión a la Base de Datos: " . mysql_error()); 
     }else{
  $imgAlbum = "tmpAlbums/"; 
  $archivo = $_FILES['fl_album']['tmp_name'];
  $nombrearchivo = $_FILES['fl_album']['name']; 

  move_uploaded_file($archivo, $imgAlbum."/".$nombrearchivo); 

  $imgAlbum = $imgAlbum."/".$nombrearchivo;
  $saveIMG = mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO imagephp VALUES('".$imgAlbum."')");
     }         
    }
?>

<div class="albumes">
   <img src="<?php echo ($imgAlbum); ?>" alt="">
   <?php            
    $selectURL = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT URL_img FROM imagephp");
    while ($url = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectURL)) {
     echo "<img src='$url'/>";
    }
    var_dump($url);
    ?>
  </div>
```

Estoy obviando un mar de codigo porque es obvio que ustedes saben y entienden lo que haría falta, como body etc, pero lo que está ahí es porque es lo único que quiero que me ayuden en eso.

Les agradezco de antemano y les pido de favor que entiendan que hablan con un novato... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La variable `$url` tiene un arreglo de objetos, no puedes decirle al `src` de la imagen que su ruta es un arreglo, tienes que sacar la ruta de ese arreglo, en este caso el campo  `URL_img`

```
$selectURL = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT URL_img FROM imagephp");
while ($url = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectURL) ) {
  echo "<img src='".$url['URL_img ']."'/>";
}
```

Comment: Me dice ahora unknow. :/

Comment: donde, copia el error y pegalo

Comment: No amigo, el problema era mío disculpa , jej ya está listo era eso muchas gracias me ayudastes :)